# How to refresh recyclerview data everyseconds without blink or scroll top

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, blink

i have a recyclerview that must refresh every 1second but i don't want to user be noticed about refreshing (like clear all recyclerview and scroll from top agin)
this is my codes

```
final Runnable refreshrunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (callbackCall != null && callbackCall.isExecuted()) callbackCall.cancel();
          /* requestListpost just gives data from retrofit and sends them to the array list */

            requestListPostApi3();

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         mAdapter.resetListData();


        }
    };


    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(refreshrunnable);

        }



    }, 0, 1000);
```

and in my adapter

```
 public void resetListData() {

        items.clear();

    }
```

when i remove "**items.clear**" everything seems ok but not ok because just adds data to recyclerview without clearing old data.
but problem is when i put this "**items.clear**" in here , recyclerview blinks and scroll moving to top every seconds .
so , what can i do about this .thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to do this every second? this is a terrible idea

Comment: i want a list like chats list in telegram that must be updated every time (when a name changes or  picture or ...) but without blinking or refreshing whole view

Comment: Updating the list with new messages is not accomplished like this, you should be using push notifications to notify your app of a new message, then your app gets the message and your list refreshes. What you are suggesting is very very bad. It will make your app run slow, kill the battery and use so much unnecessary data

Comment: Thank you this is a good Tip. 
but anyway when the app Receives the push , recycler must be refreshed ... and there is my problem

Comment: the app gets the push you then call `notifyItemInserted` on the adapter with the new index and only that item is effected. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)